# Delete map after pressing reset button on shiny

Tags: r, google-maps, shiny

I am not able to delete the generated map after I press the reset button on shiny, could you help me to insert the code to delete the map made after pressing the button? For both `selectInput` works normally, only the map that is not deleted from the screen.

```
  library(shiny)
  library(shinythemes)
  library(lubridate)
  library(googleway)
  
  set_key("API KEY")
  
  
  df1<- structure(
    list(
      Marketname = c("Market1","Market1", "Market2","Market2", "Market3", "Market3", "Market4", "Market4"),
      Latitude = c(-22.900200453490385, -22.900200453490385,-22.89279876292728,-22.89279876292728,-22.89107669207457,-22.89107669207457,-22.91668421655409,-22.91668421655409),
      Longitude = c(-48.448779371935494,-48.448779371935494, -48.45043377250408,-48.45043377250408,-48.44108027972275,-48.44108027972275,-48.43786997555729,-48.43786997555729)),
    row.names = c(NA, 8L), class = "data.frame")
  
  
  ui <- fluidPage(  
    shiny::navbarPage(theme = shinytheme("flatly"), collapsible = TRUE,
                      br(),
                      tabPanel("Rota",
                               sidebarLayout(
                                 sidebarPanel(
                                   selectizeInput("market1", label = h5("Choose starting point:"), choices = NULL, 
                                                  multiple = TRUE,
                                                  options = list(maxItems = 1)),
                                   
                                   selectizeInput("market2", label = h5("Choose destination point:"), choices = NULL, 
                                                  multiple = TRUE,
                                                  options = list(maxItems = 1)),
                                   
                                   actionButton(inputId = "getRoute", label = "Get route"),
                                   actionButton(inputId = "reset", label = "Reset")),
  
                                 mainPanel(
                                   tabsetPanel(      
                                     tabPanel("Route",google_mapOutput(outputId = "mapWarsaw"),
                                     )
                                   ))
                               ))))
  
  server <- function(input, output,session) {
    
    
    observe({
      updateSelectizeInput(session, "market1",
                           choices = unique(df1$Marketname)
      )
    })
    
    
    observe({
      excludeOption <- NULL
      if (!is.null(input$market1)) {
        excludeOption <- input$market1
      }
      
      updateSelectizeInput(session, "market2",
                           choices = unique(df1$Marketname[df1$Marketname != excludeOption])
      )
    })
    
    observeEvent(input$getRoute, {
      origin <- df1[df1$Marketname == input$market1, c("Latitude", "Longitude")][1, ]
      
      destination <- df1[df1$Marketname == input$market2, c("Latitude", "Longitude")][1, ]
    
      route <- google_directions(origin = origin, 
                                 destination = destination,
                                 mode = "driving")
      
      df_routes <- data.frame(polyline = direction_polyline(route))
      
      df_way <- cbind(
        route$routes$legs[[1]]$end_location,
        data.frame(address = route$routes$legs[[1]]$end_address)
      )
      
      
      m3<-google_map() %>%
        add_polylines(data = df_routes, polyline = "polyline", stroke_weight = 4)
      
      output$mapWarsaw <- renderGoogle_map({
        m3
      })
    })
    
     observeEvent(input$reset, {
       updateSelectInput(session, "market1", selected = "")
       updateSelectInput(session, "market2", selected = "")
                
  })
    
  }
  
  shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Here I pressed reset, the `selectInput` was cleared, but the map was not, so I would like to insert some code that cleared the screen. Of course, after inserting the `selectInput` options again, the map was generated normally on the screen.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using a `reactiveVal` to store whether you want to plot or not, then `req(.)` that value in your plot.

A simple example:

```r
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      numericInput("n", "N", value = 2),
      actionButton("toggle", "Toggle")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("plot")
    )
  )
)
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  doplot <- reactiveVal(TRUE)
  observeEvent(input$toggle, {
    doplot(!isTRUE(doplot()))
  })
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    req(doplot())
    plot(runif(input$n))
  })
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

- `doplot` defaults to `TRUE`, so it starts plotting immediately (assuming `input$n` has a value), and every time `input$n` is changed, a new plot is rendered;
- when you click on `toggle`, the `doplot` is inverted, and the dependent `output$plot` will "fail" the `req(doplot())` requirement and clear the plot;
- this could be improved to give a clearer indication that the empty plot is because the user toggled the button ... in this case, I should likely change the style of the button to clearly indicate the state, but that's aesthetics and may or may not apply to your app

Another similar method would be to store the *data* in a `reactiveVal`, and `req`uire it, perhaps like this:

```r
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      numericInput("n", "N", value = 2),
      actionButton("toggle", "Toggle")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("plot")
    )
  )
)
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  mydat <- reactiveVal(NULL)
  observeEvent(input$toggle, {
    req(input$n)
    if (is.null(mydat())) {
      mydat(runif(input$n))
    } else mydat(NULL)
  })
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    plot(req(mydat()))
  })
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

This second method won't work as well if you need to preserve the data.

Comment: Hi @r2evans, sorry for the late reply. I really appreciate your detailed answer, I tried to use yours as a basis for tweaking my code, but unfortunately I didn't get good results. Would it be possible for you to try to adjust my question code? Even if it doesn't work 100%, I know I'll be on the right track. Thank you again!

Comment: I don't use googlemaps in R, so I can't replicate that portion of it. In general, you're mis-using `observe*`. To start, `output$mapWarsaw` should not be within an `observe`, it should be at the same level. (There are times I guess when nesting observe/reactive blocks can make sense, but I suggest that they are bespoke corner-cases better handled with controlling reactivity in other ways.) I suggest you start by converting `observeEvent(input$getRoute` so that it returns the _data_ (not a plot), then put `google_map() ...` inside `renderGoogle_map(...)`.